# Infinitely rotate two variables using CAAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I am calling users "Weight" from firebase database in a label (which is stored under 'profile/uid') which has two categories "kg" and "lbs". I would like the label to be able to show user's weight in kg and then fade out to lbs and then back to kg again so on and so fourth. So far i have written the following code which is constantly fading in and out the weight in lbs and i'm unsure how to get it to display the weight in kg once lbs fades out:

```
func weight() {

    let userRf = self.firDatabaseRef.child("profile").child("\(User!.uid)").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let weight = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "weight").value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let kg = weight["kg"] as? Float, let lbs = weight["lbs"] as? Int {

                    let animation: CATransition = CATransition()
                    animation.duration = 2.0
                    animation.type = kCATransitionFade
                    animation.repeatDuration = .infinity
                    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
                    self.displayWeight.layer.add(animation, forKey: "changeTextTransition")

                    self.displayWeight.text = "\(lbs) lbs"

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a repeating `UIVIew` animation along with a `Timer`:

```
// set up some helpful constants
let kgsText = "\(kgs) kgs"
let lbsText = "\(lbs) lbs"
let fadeDuration = 2.0

// keep track of which unit is being displayed
var isDisplayingKgs = true

// animate the fade in and out, repeating
UIView.animate(withDuration: fadeDuration, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    label.alpha = 0
}, completion: nil)

// start the timer to switch the text after a short delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + fadeDuration) {
    self.displayWeight.text = lbsText
    isDisplayingKgs = false
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: fadeDuration * 2, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        self.displayWeight.text = isDisplayingKgs ? lbsText : kgsText
        isDisplayingKgs = !isDisplayingKgs
    })
}
```

This is assuming that your label starts out visible (alpha = 1). The dispatch delay is to ensure that the first transition occurs when the label is faded out the first time, but before the timer kicks in.

Here is what the animation looks like in action:

[image: gif of the label animation]

Comment: just another quick question, if i had more than 2 variables to display using a timer which may or may not be present, how could i achieve that? so far i have used an if statement within the timer to display each variable one buy one if they are present but when the timer reaches the last variable it doesn't then come back to the first if statement to display the first variable again hence it's stuck displaying the last variable.

Comment: @UmarYaqub First you would need to determine how many items you want to display by checking if they are present. Then I would add them to an array. The animation code would have to be refactored to account for any number of items, but shouldn't be that hard to rotate through the elements in the array every time the timer block fires.

Comment: @UmarYaqub Instead of a tracker boolean like `isDisplayingKgs`, you would need to keep track of the currently displayed item in the array with an  index-tracking variable like `currentItemIndex`, which is an `Int`.